# MonoTouch fails to launch XCode

Tags: xcode, macos, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

whenever I try to open a .XIB file by doubleclick, I get the following error:

The file "project.xcworkspace" doesn't exist

> System.Exception: Error ScriptError: Xcode got an error: Connection is invalid.
>     at MonoDevelop.MacInterop.AppleScript.Run (Boolean compile, MonoDevelop.MacInterop.AEDesc& scriptData) [0x00012] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MacPlatform/MacInterop/AppleScript.cs:107 
>     at MonoDevelop.MacInterop.AppleScript.Run (System.String scriptSource) [0x00010] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MacPlatform/MacInterop/AppleScript.cs:83 
>     at MonoDevelop.MacInterop.AppleScript.Run (System.String scriptSourceFormat, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MacPlatform/MacInterop/AppleScript.cs:74 
>     at MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeMonitor.OpenFile (System.String relativeName) [0x0001a] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/XcodeSyncing/XcodeMonitor.cs:283 
>     at MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeProjectTracker.OpenFileInXcodeProject (System.String path) [0x00056] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/XcodeSyncing/XcodeProjectTracker.cs:166

I have tried to reinstall XCode 4.2, without success. I am using MT5.0.4, MD2.8.5, M2.10.8

Any ideas?

Thanks for your time on this!

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the order you are installing things? Don't you have to install XCode and SDK before all the mono stuff?

Comment: MonoTouch support is on this (great support indeed!), it's probably a corrupt file. I'll post more when they reply